# Issues with async tests using fetch and spyOn in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, jestjs

I am having an issue where the final case of the `test.each` block below seems to run with the real implementation of `fetch()` rather than the spy version.

```
  describe('renders correct number of components', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
      jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });

    test.each([1,2,3,4])('renders %i components', async (componentCount) => {
      jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockResolvedValueOnce({
        json: async () => ({ components: componentCount })
      } as Response);

      render(<ParentComponent />);
      
      expect(await screen.findAllByText(/my component/i)).toHaveLength(componentCount);
    });
  });
```

The real implementation is:

```
  const getSomeData = async (): Promise<ComponentData> => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080', { method: "GET" });
    return res.json();
  }
```

When I run the tests the first 3 pass fine, however the 4th throws a `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080`.  If I remove the 4th test the same happens with the 3rd.

If I change `http://localhost:8080` to something like `https://google.com` I get a warning about a 'worker process failing to exit gracefully' but the tests all pass and there are no errors.

It seems to me that somehow the restored `fetch()` is making it through to the final test without being remocked by `spyOn()` but I can't for the life of me see how.

Comment: Definitely weird. I think your observation is accurate. Does moving `jest.restoreAllMocks()` into the last line of the test block resolve the issue somehow?

Comment: Hey @Jackyef yeah I've tried moving it both before and after the `expect()`, same result though, 4th test fails others are fine, thanks!

Comment: I see. Is there any possibility that the `<ParentComponent />` is calling fetch more than once? Say, if we throw a `console.log()` in the function that calls fetch, does it always only log once for each of the test cases?

Comment: Only getting one output in the console.